# jQuery tooltip displaying timeAgo from unix timestamp

Tags: jquery, time, tooltip, timeago

How can I get **timeAgo** from **timestamp** in jquery and display it as a simple **tooltip**?

I found this http://timeago.yarp.com/ which is not exactly what I want.

What I'm looking for is putting the timestamp as let's say `data-ts="timestamp"` and then when the user hovers the text, a tooltip is shown as "1 day, 3 hours ago".

NB: The tooltip is not meant to be a special thing, just the default system tooltip that shows the title attribute is sufficient.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferred to use a server side function to convert a timestamp to "timeAgo" and add it as an attribute of the element and simply show it in the tooltip?

Comment: Yes I can do it and I already did but in this particular situation I want it to be with jQuery to be realtime

Answer (score 1):

While you mentioned it's not exactly what you want, you can use [timago.yarp.com](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to achieve it. There's an option to use it programmatically:

```
jQuery.timeago(new Date());             //=> "less than a minute ago"
jQuery.timeago("2008-07-17");           //=> "9 years ago"
jQuery.timeago(jQuery("time#some_id")); //=> "9 years ago"     // [title="2008-07-20"]
```

For instance:

```
$('.element-with-tooltip').hover(function(){
$(this).attr('data-timeago', $.timeago($(this).attr('data-ts')));
});
```

A better approach would be to add it as a callback of the ToolTip function (plugin) that returns the "timeago" output to show in the tooltip.